# Problems When Converting String that Contains a Period (.) to Int32 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, int32

I'm creating a POS (Point Of Sale) and I've come across a problem when trying to convert the price "`0.60`" to an integer.

Data Background: All the Data for the Data Source is from a MySQL database that I have setup and connected with no problems.

The Price is Stored in a TextBox and is formatted as such "`0.60`", I believe that this is the reason why it isn't being converted. I keep getting the message below.

> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
        //Puts the Price Into a String.
        string NewPrice = txtPrice.Text;

        //Converts The Quantity In the TextBox field to a numbers.
        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuant.Text);

        //Incorrect Format & Attempt One.
        //Price = Convert.ToInt32(NewPrice); <--- Problem.
        //Price = int.Parse(NewPrice);

        // I've also tried this method below with two '0' inside the { } brackets.
        // But Still No Luck.
        Price = Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0.00}",txtPrice.Text)); // <--- Problem.

        // Times Price & Quantity to get Total Price (0.60 * 2 = 1.20)
        TotalSingleItemPrice = Price * Quantity;

        // The Single Item Price is added into the overall total.
        TotalPrice += TotalSingleItemPrice;

        // Converts Total Item Price to String from Int.
        string TotalPriceStr = Convert.ToString(TotalSingleItemPrice);           

        // Puts TextBoxes / Strings Into One String array (I think).
        string[] InizialItemList = new string[] { cmboInitItem.Text, Convert.ToString(Price), Convert.ToString(Quantity), TotalPriceStr};

        // Adds The String Array Into the Data Grid View.
        DGVIIL.Rows.Add(InizialItemList);
```

I've tried to use the `string.Format("{0.00}",txtPrice.Text)` setup to combat this problem, I just can't see what I have over looked. I would like the Price to appear in my DataGridView - DGVIIL, as `0.60` if possible.

Comment: 0.60 is not an integer...

Comment: An integer cannot contain a decimal point, you should convert to a float or decimal

Comment: @TMcKeown I know It's not an integer. Is there any reasonable way to get around this? Could you should be an example with Float or Decimal? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: i updated my answer with an alternative.

Comment: While some have suggested using float or double, since you are dealing with currency you should use Decimal. @TMcKeown had a good answer below, although you may consider using a Decimal.TryParse().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0.60` is not an integer, the error is right on

Alternatives:

```
Decimal d = Decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
```

Or even better:

```
Decimal d;
if ( decimal.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out d) == false ){
  //handle bad number...
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but it could be better with a Decimal.TryParse().

Comment: Thank you, I've just used the Decimal d as you have stated and it worked. Now I will add TryParse() as Rick Davin stated and Yuval Itzchakov for Validation Reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `decimal.Parse` or `Convert.ToDecimal` as your string is clearly not an `int`. Decimal is recommanded as you're dealing with currency.

```
Price = Convert.ToDecimal(NewPrice);
Price = decimal.Parse(NewPrice);
```

Also, I suggest you look into `TryParse` to use for validation:

```
decimal price;
if (decimal.TryParse(NewPrice, out price))
{ // do stuff }
```

Comment: Should double be avoided when dealing with currency?

Comment: If you're dealing with currency, use `decimal`. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert it to double, then to int.

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32( Convert.ToDouble("1.11")); 

//Expected output: x = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Price = Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0.00}",txtPrice.Text));
```

in the above code you are converting from a decimal style format to an integer. the int32 type can only contain whole integer numbers and thus the convert method will give you an error. Instead you can use the type of a double to hold your value properly.

```
double Price;
Price = Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0.00}",txtPrice.Text));
```